# How to load data from a text file in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: database, postgresql, csv

I have a file like (CSV file):

```
value1|value2|value2....

value1|value2|value2....

value1|value2|value2....

value1|value2|value2....
```

and would like to load these data into a postgresql table.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The slightly modified version of [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) below worked better for me, where I specify the [`CSV`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html#AEN72023) format. This format treats backslash characters in text without any fuss. The default format is the somewhat quirky [`TEXT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html#AEN71940).

```sql
COPY myTable FROM '/path/to/file/on/server' ( FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER('|') );
```

Comment: If you're using `psql` and the file is in a location not accessible to the *server* (but only to the client), use the exact same command except start with `\copy`.

Comment: for those who want to skip the first line of the CSV file, use HEADER option, like in `COPY myTable FROM '/path/to/file/on/server' ( FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER('|') , HEADER);`

Comment: @Wildcard Great comment.

Answer (score 18):

Let consider that your data are in the file `values.txt` and that you want to import them in the database table `myTable` then the following query does the job

```
COPY myTable FROM 'value.txt' (DELIMITER('|'));
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: It needs quotes around the filename/filepath. Could you please update your answer with `COPY myTable FROM 'value.txt' (DELIMITER('|'));`

Answer (score 6):

Check out the COPY command of Postgres:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 3):

There's [Pgloader](http://pgloader.io/) that uses the aforementioned `COPY` command and which can load data from csv (and MySQL, SQLite and dBase). It's also using separate threads for reading and copying data, so it's quite fast (interestingly enough, it got written from Python to Common Lisp and got a 20 to 30x speed gain, see [blog post](http://tapoueh.org/blog/2014/05/14-pgloader-got-faster.html)).

To load the csv file one needs to write a little configuration file, like

```
LOAD CSV  
  FROM 'path/to/file.csv' (x, y, a, b, c, d)  
  INTO postgresql:///pgloader?csv (a, b, d, c)  
  …
```

Answer (score 0):

```
COPY description_f (id, name) FROM 'absolutepath\test.txt' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true, DELIMITER '   ');

Example

COPY description_f (id, name) FROM 'D:\HIVEWORX\COMMON\TermServerAssets\Snomed2021\SnomedCT\Full\Terminology\sct2_Description_Full_INT_20210131.txt' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true, DELIMITER ' ');
```