# How to import data from a text file into a specific PostgreSQL column?

Tags: postgresql

I have a text file which contains `val1`

And my table in PostgesSql is in format

`val1 | val2 | val3 | ...`

**Edited** : 
When I tried writing the command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233321/how-to-load-data-from-a-text-file-in-a-postgresql-database/21361964), Following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7ZYv.png) is shown.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233321/how-to-load-data-from-a-text-file-in-a-postgresql-database/21361964

Comment: An error is thrown. I edited the post and it is elaborated their.

Comment: What do you not understand about `relation "mytable" does not exist` ?  It does mean that you will have to create the table in postgresql yourself, before trying to import data.

Comment: After that, I can then write this command and follow that link?

Comment: Maybe look at this link, it works better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250167/invalid-input-syntax-for-type-integer-in-postgresql#comment106572054_60250167  (only change tablename, and you use different delimiter...)

Comment: Okay, I got what you are trying to mean. `Copy [the name of the table(the name of the column)] from 'path'`. I tried it, now new error is showing, error `could not open file "C:\Users\User\Downloads\your desired name.txt" for reading: Permission denied
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
SQL state: 42501`

Comment: Try: `type myinput.csv | psql -d mytest -c "COPY mytable(myfiel1, myfield2, myfield3) FROM STDIN DELIMITER ';' CSV ;"`   (replace all parts starting with `my` with their correct names.

Comment: `Syntax Error at or near "type"`

Comment: Than i am sorry to say that i cannot help you any more, because there is not enough info on my side to do so.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a drop option in a table, there import the .txt file in the drop-down options with corresponding column name. Later refresh the table, then view it. Walah, you got table exactly as your .txt file. Thank You.