# Why am I getting "Invalid input syntax for type integer" in postgresql when importing a CSV?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, byte-order-mark

I'm trying to import a .csv file to my postgresql DB.
I created a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts
(
    acc_id integer,
    acc_name text,
    website text,
    lat numeric,
    longe numeric,
    primary_poc text,
    sales_rep_id integer
)
```

Then I used the following command to import the .csv file

```
COPY accounts(acc_id,acc_name,website,lat,longe,primary_poc,sales_rep_id) 
FROM 'D:\accounts.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV ;
```

And my .csv file contains the following:

```
1;Walmart;www.walmart.com;40.23849561;-75.10329704;Tamara Tuma;321500
2;Exxon Mobil;www.exxonmobil.com;41.16915630;-73.84937379;Sung Shields;321510
3;Apple;www.apple.com;42.29049481;-76.08400942;Jodee Lupo;321520
```

However, this doesn't work and the following message appear:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "1"
CONTEXT:  COPY accounts, line 1, column acc_id: "1"
SQL state: 22P02
```

Comment: Try: `\copy accounts from 'D:\accounts.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV;`

Comment: It gave the same error

Comment: Do you have a header? If so, try adding "HEADER" ...FROM 'D:/accounts/csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;

Comment: @hamzaboulahia . . . Try loading into a staging table where all the columns are strings.  See if that works.  You can then do the conversions in the database.

Comment: An example with COPY:  `type accounts.csv | psql -d test -c "COPY accounts(acc_id,acc_name,website,lat,longe,primary_poc,sales_rep_id) FROM STDIN DELIMITER ';' CSV ;" `

Comment: @lydiaHendriks I don't have a header in the .csv file.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I tried using TEXT as the column type and it worked but again I think this is not a good solution for this problem.

Comment: Maybe there is a BOM in the CSV? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: The .csv file was generated using MS Excel.

Comment: The plot tightens ... [hexdump the file, and inspect the first three characters]

Comment: I don't know how to do that :/

Comment: Have anyone of you tried the code to see if it works on a machine other than mine?

Comment: Yes, i tried, and even gave two different options on how to import those 3 lines.

Comment: Yes, it works here. (after adding a `;` to the table definition)

Comment: Okay, I'll try that

Comment: @wildplasser: `powershell "type accounts.csv | format-hex"`

Comment: @luuk `dd skip=3 bs=1 if=oldfile of=newfile`

Comment: here is the hex format https://snipboard.io/Q3mie8.jpg

Comment: Maybe `type` ignores the BOM? (i's a feature, not a bug ...)

Comment: just tested, it does  (on Windows), indeed a feature, so do `powershell "format-hex accounts.csv"` to chheck for the BOM, If it starts with a BOM you will see `EF BB BF` as first 3 bytes.

Comment: I see no BOM on my powershell. I'll try with another .csv and see

Comment: Never trust Excel spreadsheets, always load to a staging table where they can be validated and corrected before loading to production tables. You think they're safe. [Think again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yb2zkxHDfUE&t=42s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there is a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the CSV?

- hexdump the file, and inspect the first three characters
- (and) use an editor to remove the BOM
- (or) export again, without the BOM (there should be a checkmark, even in the Microsoft "software")