# Upload images in database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want save uploaded images in a `bytea` column in my PostgreSQL database. I'm looking for advice on how to how to save images from Rails into a `bytea` column, preferably with examples.

I use Rails 3.1 with the "pg" driver to connect to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please show code you've written attempting to solve the problem.

Comment: Now I just load the file into the folder, but I need to keep it in the database. I've only been programming ASP.NET and is now studying ruby. I know how to do it in .NET and I need an example on Rails.

Comment: @user1466717 Which PostgreSQL driver for Ruby are you using? [`ruby-pg`](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-pg)?

Comment: I use gem pg http://rubygems.org/gems/pg

Comment: @user1466717 Then see https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/src/ef533f731814/sample/test_binary_values.rb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It's often not a good idea to store images in the database its self

See the discussions on [is it better to store images in a BLOB or just the URL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/736/is-it-better-to-store-images-in-a-blob-or-just-the-url) and [Files - in the database or not?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/files-in-the-database-or-not). Be aware that those questions and their answers aren't about PostgreSQL specifically.

There are some PostgreSQL specific wrinkles to this. PostgreSQL doesn't have any facilities for incremental dumps<sup>*</sup>, so if you're using `pg_dump` backups you have to dump all that image data for every backup. Storage space and transfer time can be a concern, especially since you should be keeping several weeks' worth of backups, not just a single most recent backup.

If the images are large or numerous you might want to  consider storing images in the file system unless you have a strong need for transactional, ACID-compliant access to them. Store file names in the database, or just establish a convention of file naming based on a useful key. That way you can do easy incremental backups of the image directory, managing it separately to the database proper.

If you store the images in the FS you can't easily<sup>†</sup> access them via the PostgreSQL database connection. OTOH you can serve them directly over HTTP directly from the file system much more efficiently than you could *ever* hope to when you have to query them from the DB first. In particular you [can use sendfile() from rails](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Ruby-on-Rails/Managing-Database-Files-with-Ruby-on-Rails) if your images are on the FS, but not from a database.

### If you really must store the images in the DB

... then it's conceptually the same as in .NET, but the exact details depend on the Pg driver you're using, which you didn't specify.

There are two ways to do it:

- Store and retrieve `bytea`, as you asked about; and
- Use the built-in large object support, which is often preferable to using `bytea`.

### For small images where bytea is OK:

- Read the image data from the client into a local variable
- Insert that into the DB by passing the variable as bytea. Assuming you're using the `ruby-pg` driver the [test_binary_values](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/src/ef533f731814/sample/test_binary_values.rb) example from the driver should help you.

### For bigger images (more than a few megabytes) use `lo` instead:

For bigger images please don't use `bytea`. It's theoretical max may be 2GB, but [in practice you need 3x the RAM (or more) as the image size would suggest](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/query-max-size-Bytea-td1976679.html) so you should avoid using `bytea` for large images or other large binary data.

PostgreSQL has a [dedicated `lo` (large object) type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html) for that. On 9.1 just:

```
CREATE EXTENSION lo;
CREATE TABLE some_images(id serial primary key, lo image_data not null);
```

... then use [`lo_import`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo-interfaces.html) to read the data from a temporary file that's on disk, so you don't have to fit the whole thing in RAM at once.

The driver `ruby-pg` provides [wrapper calls](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html) for `lo_create`, `lo_open`, etc, and provides a `lo_import` for local file access too. See [this useful example](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/src/default/sample/losample.rb).

Please use large objects rather than `bytea`.

---

<sup>*</sup> Incremental backup is possible with streaming replication, PITR / WAL archiving, etc, but again increasing the DB size can complicate things like WAL management. Anyway, unless you're an expert (or "brave") you should be taking `pg_dump` backups rather than relying on repliation and PITR alone. Putting images in your DB will also - by increasing the size of your DB - greatly slow down `pg_basebackup`, which can be important in failover scenarios.

<sup>†</sup> The [adminpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879378/how-to-insert-a-text-file-into-a-field-in-postgresql) offers local file access via a Pg connection for superusers. Your webapp user should *never* have superuser rights or even ownership of the tables it works with, though. Do your file reads and writes via a separate secure channel like `WebDAV`.

Comment: The idea is as follows. My files will be stored in the database and file system. If the file is removed from the file system, it will again be automatically loaded from the database file and stored in a folder.

Comment: @user1466717 Urk, why? That's the worst of both worlds. What problem are you trying to solve with this approach? What's the underlying problem, the reason why you want to do that?

Comment: @user1466717 BTW, answer updated with links to [the examples in the ruby-pg tests](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/src/ef533f731814/sample/test_binary_values.rb) for `bytea` access.

Comment: When you view the page images will be issued from the file system. If the transfer or accidental deletion of files, the first page load is a picture from the base-loaded and configured from scratch. This will save all the images and do not load the database each time the page loads.

Comment: @user1466717: whether to store image in the file system or in the database, see also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/736/is-it-better-to-store-images-in-a-blob-or-just-the-url

Comment: @user1466717 OK, that sounds like a very strange approach, but whatever works for you I guess. To me it sounds more like a job for the application, copying default images from a read-only directory, zip archive, or whatever. Still, if they're small images or you don't mind big backups it won't hurt.

Comment: In case of storing the images in the filesystem and keeping only a link to the image in the database, PostgreSQL can also automatically delete the file when the link is deleted, see [here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Ruby-on-Rails/More-Advanced-Database-Features-and-Rails/)

Comment: @jug That refers to large objects, which are *within* the database. The `lo` pseudo-type takes care of this for you with no custom coding, so it's a safer option than hand-rolling triggers for the job. For managing external files you can `NOTIFY` a `LISTEN`ing process to tell it to delete the file; ideally your database shouldn't have any more file system access than it absolutely needs to so it shouldn't be deleting them its self.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Thanks for the info, somehow I misunderstood that paragraph.