# How can I store images in my heroku postgres DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cocoa-touch, heroku

I've found some similar questions, and good link on the topic. Such as this one ([Easiest way to store images in database on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122906/easiest-way-to-store-images-in-database-on-heroku)), where the top answer is to re-think using their DB and instead go with S3.

What I need is store 120 100KB images. That's it. There is no dynamic aspect. It's not like I have 10,000 users, and each one needs to store their profile picture. None of that. I just need to store 120 100KB images. The amount of images will never never change, neither growing or shrinking. 3 years from now, the same 120 images will be all that there is.

For these reasons, I want to store these in my DB. S3 is overkill, could cost some, extra time and cost needed implementing that solution, etc. In my DB, it's a measly 12MB which is a fraction of a fraction of the DB's total size.

How can I store the images? What datatype should I use and how can I upload them into my DB?

Answer (score 1):

Just store them as `bytea` fields in a table. Insert them using a script in whatever your preferred language is and its database adapter. e.g. using Python with `psycopg2` you'd `open('filename','rb')` the file, then pass it as a query parameter to the `execute` method when doing your `INSERT`.

For images that small there's no point using `pg_largeobject` and the `lo` wrapper, which can be useful for really big files. The only real advantage of that is that you can use `lo_import` to read the files directly into the database.