# Images are saved to folder but not to database

Tags: php, android, android-volley, image-uploading

I'm working on how to upload image from android application to server (here I'm using wamp) using volley.For me,images are not saved in mysql database but successfully stored in folder I made?Please help me for rectifying this issue?I"ll post my codes below:

code i used in android:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView textView;
Button select,upload;
private final static int  PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST=1;
ImageView imageView;
String FileName,FilePath;
private Bitmap bitmap;
public static final String FILE_UPLOAD_URL="http://192.168.187.1/progressdemo/upload.php";
private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private String KEY_NAME = "name";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    select=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    upload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    select.setOnClickListener(this);
    upload.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

               Uri filepath=data.getData();
                FilePath=filepath.toString();
             FileName=FilePath.substring(FilePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                textView.setText(FileName);
                try {
                    //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filepath);
                    //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==select)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select file"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
    else if (v==upload)
    {
       uploadfile();
    }


}
private void uploadfile()
{
    final ProgressDialog progress=ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading image...","....Please wait..",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, FILE_UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {

                    progress.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast message of the response
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            progress.dismiss();
            //Showing toast message of the response
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            String name=textView.getText().toString();
            String image=getStringImage(bitmap);
            Map<String,String> params=new Hashtable<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_IMAGE,image);
            params.put(KEY_NAME,name);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp)
{

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
    byte[] imagebytes=baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedimage= Base64.encodeToString(imagebytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedimage;
}
}
```

codes I used in php:

```
 <?php

 header('Content-type:bitmap;charset=utf-8');
 if(isset($_POST["image"]))
 {
 $encoded_string=$_POST["image"];
 $name=$_POST["name"];
 $decoded_string=base64_decode($encoded_string);
 $path='images/'.$name;
 $file=fopen($path,'w');
 $is_written=fwrite($file,$decoded_string);
 fclose($file);
 if($is_written>0)
 {
 $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','progressdemo');
 echo "connection success\n";
 $path = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $path);
 $query="insert into volleyupload(photo,name)values('".$path."','".$name."');";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

if($result)
 {
 echo "success";

 }
 else{

 echo "failure";
 }

  mysqli_close($con);
  }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Because you don't write the binary data in the database? You're only inserting the path + name. Or you mean, the path+name aren't inserted?

Comment: In my database I've made fields like photo and name in datatype varchar.I want to store path to photo and name of image to name field.But this is failing

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/11929145/3885509

Comment: I just want to insert the path and name..But it's not working..Is there any error in my php script..I got path when toasted in app.But insertion not occuring

Comment: thank you all for helping me..I made a new table in database and all went fine..

Comment: For the next time, post the mysqli_error($link) if the insert failed. Probably that answers your question even before asking it here ;)